# Laravel Email Blade Template route Not Work

Tags: php, laravel, queue, email-templates

I am mailing to the users using the queue job. sent mail in background. but when I am sent mail direct to the user `{{route('')}}` work properly, but not with queue job.

Code in My Email Blade File:

`{{ route('trainer.check_status') }}`

**Normal Mail:**

`http://mydomail.test/trainer/check_status`

**With Queue Job**

`http://localhost/trainer/check_status`

please help me to out this issue.

Comment: seems like you are checking with `localhost` that's why its add `http://localhost...` don't use route method on your blade email template, use domain url instead

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've defined the url in `.env` file after making this job. You need to reset your job to clear its cache.
Try running below command in your terminal

```
php artisan queue:restart
```